# `sudo passwd` asking for old password / reset recovery key

Tags: macos, command-line, security, password, permission

I'm an `admin` on my Mac (macOS Montrey 12.5), but forgot my own password.

I can login remotely from another machine (SSH key based auth), and I have `sudo` configured with `NOPASSWD` for the `admin` group. So I'm able to run any `sudo` command; however, I cannot change my own password!

`passwd` asks for the old password (!), and `dscl` / `sysadminctl` didn't seem to work either. I tried:

```
$ sudo passwd me
Changing password for me.
Old password:

$ sudo sysadminctl -resetPasswordFor me -newPassword passw0rd
2022-08-01 12:00:00.000 sysadminctl[6735:297889] Operation is not permitted without secure token unlock.

$ sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/me
New Password:
Permission denied. Please enter user's old password:
```

I also tried running the above commands as `root` by doing `sudo zsh` first. But got the same results.

When I boot into Recovery Mode (`Command-R` while booting), I select `Forgot all password?` it prompts for:

```
Enter your recovery key to unlock the volume "Macintosh HD"
```

*(I'm certain I've setup macOS with FaileVault off, but it seems one of the OS upgrades enabled it for me.)*

Attempting to turn off File Vault still prompts for the admin user password:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/fdesetup disable
Enter the user name:me
Enter the password for user 'me':
FileVault was not disabled (11).
```

When I boot into Single User Mode (`Command-S` while booting), macOS Montrey now enters into a GUI screen and prompts for the password. (I guess due to FileVaule?)

Is it possible to reset my password or regenerate a new *Recovery Key* from the command-line?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This [article](https://www.cleverfiles.com/help/reset-password-mac-howto.html?amp) may help you. May be quite old but you may find some interesting tips

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this counts as an "answer", but **I managed to turn off FileVault**! Despite the error:

```
Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges.
```

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/fdesetup disable
Enter the user name:notadmin
Enter the password for user 'notadmin':
2022-08-08 10:00:00.000 fdesetup[650:5380] set accountPolicies error :Error Domain=com.apple.OpenDirectory Code=4001 "Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Operation was denied because the current credentials do not have the appropriate privileges.}
FileVault has been disabled.

$ sudo /usr/bin/fdesetup disable
FileVault is already Off.
```

After that, I booted into Recovery Mode (`Command-R` while booting), opened a terminal and typed:

```
resetpassword
```

I select `Forgot all password?` and it forced me to change the password of every single user on the Mac.

I rebooted the machine, and was able to login using the newly reset password.

Comment: Nice. I was going to suggest making a time machine backup to a disk that’s not encrypted (or is with a pass phrase you know) and then erase + install.